# Difference between Send.nc and SendMsg.nc

Tags: tinyos

What is the difference between Send and SendMsg interface in tinyos?

Answer (score 0):

`SendMsg` is an interface in TinyOS 1.x whereas `Send` is in TinyOS 2.x. It's possible to use only one of them, depending on your version of TinyOS. Probably you prefer to use the newer version.

By the way, `SendMsg` analogue in TinyOS 2.x is not `Send`, but `AMSend`. The former is used for address-free protocols and the latter for active message communication. See http://www.tinyos.net/tinyos-2.1.0/doc/html/tep116.html (especially section **2.2 Sending interfaces**).